# Webpack adding random a href links in html

Tags: html, webpack

when I bundle webpack, it adds random a href links, heres the image of where the link is supposed to be:

Good, a picture of my code in vscode

[image: 1]

Notice how there is only one link,
here is the bad:

Bad, a picture of the bundled code in the web inspector

[image: 2]

It's adding way more links.
I already searched all my files to see if I was accidentally appending links to the DOM, but I didn't

Comment: It looks like you don't have a closing `</a>` tag for the first link. My guess is the webpack HTML loader is incorrectly parsing this link, causing these duplicates. Try closing that link and re-running webpack to see what happens.